# Add marker on Google map on touching the screen using android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to **add a marker** on google map by touching the screen. Google Map is working fine. But on touching, nothing is happening. Is there another way?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

  // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
  }
  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// Setting a click event handler for the map
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            googleMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a click listener on your mMap object; OnMapClickListener. And inside the onMapClick event, put your code to add the marker.